# JS call(): Unexpected "this" context within function being called

Tags: javascript, window, this, call

Here is my experimental script:

```
window.name = 'myWindow';

function sum(num1, num2){
    console.log('context name: '+this.name+', caller: '+arguments.callee.caller.name);
}

function callSumNoName(num1, num2){
    sum.call(this, num1, num2);
}

function callSum(num1, num2){
    this.name = 'fnCallSumm';
    sum.call(this, num1, num2);
}

console.log(callSumNoName()); // no property name in the function
console.log(callSum());       // the property name is 'fnCallSumm'
console.log(callSumNoName()); // no property name in the function
```

I expected that **this.name** within function **sum()** must be:

```
myWindow
fnCallSumm
myWindow
```

...but in reality they are:

```
myWindow
fnCallSumm
fnCallSumm
```

What does it mean?! Why in the 3-th time it shows the **name** property of the function caller from **previous** time, not the name property of the window object that must be extracted now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `callSum` the `this` refers to the global object(winow) so you are actually overwriting `window.name` that is why you get `fnCallSumm` twice.

```
function callSum(num1, num2){
    this.name = 'fnCallSumm';// equivalent to `window.name = 'fnCallSumm';`
    sum.call(this, num1, num2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set the name value in a previous call.
this.name is now "fnCallSumm"

```
function callSumNoName(num1, num2){
    this.name = "myWindow";
    sum.call(this, num1, num2);
}
```